# Why is Gatsby dynamic route returning 404 on refresh in production?

Tags: reactjs, routes, http-status-code-404, gatsby, server-side-rendering

I have the following dynamic route in my Gatsby project which makes a fetch using the `job_id` param:

[image]

The route works fine when I'm developing locally, and seems to work on production when I use a Gatsby `Link` to route to it. But when I refresh the page on production, I get this 404 screen:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've read some stuff about setting up server side redirects but I don't see how that would fix it. Because I don't want `/job_details/*` routing to `/job_details`. I want it to route using the `job_id` param.